# React onClick function parameter turns into "Proxy" Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of elements at the top level of my react hierarchy that I want to set off an onClick function with a parameter with the value of the element (a string). However, when I try printing this value, a "Proxy" object is printed instead : `Proxy {dispatchConfig: null, _targetInst: null, isDefaultPrevented: null, isPropagationStopped: null, _dispatchListeners: null…}`

Here is the code inside my render function:

```
return collapseChoices.map((choice) => {
        console.log(choice)

        return (
          <div className="collapseChoice"
             onClick={(choice) => this.handleCollapse(choice)}>
             {choice}
          </div>
        );
```

Here is the handleCollapse function:

```
handleCollapse(mark){
    console.log(mark);
  }
```

I made sure to bind `this` in the constructor

```
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.handleCollapse = this.handleCollapse.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you are passing the event object into your handleCollapse method, not the choice. 
they way this reads is you are telling react that when the button is clicked execute the arrow function passing the event object to it which in term will call the handleCollapse method using the same event object. 
try doing this

`onClick={this.handleCollapse.bind(this, choice)}`

instead

Comment: Note that just removing the parameter in the arrow-notation function also works: `{() => this.handleCollapse(choice)}`.

Comment: not quite the same. because of the way handleCollapse is declared it my have unpredictable behavior specially if is relying on `this`  take a look  here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Arrow notations performs a binding over `this` appropriately. Under the hoods, transpilers use a code quite similar to what you provided.

Comment: The link you provided, at the end, has a comment like this: `// This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick`. Arrow notations are just a syntactic sugar. It is just an aestetical matter to me. Your solution works also perfectly. Just a different taste.

Comment: i have to apologize, because the comment was cut on your `() =>` i did not see it. but you are right they do the same and yes is a matter of preference.